# Why web server should clear away socket receive buffer before sending response?

Tags: c, sockets, webserver

I am studying a tiny web server, it can receive GET-request from browser and return an html file. The `serve_file`-function sends response messages to browser, and the `get_line`-function gets a line from socket buffer. I don't know why must *read & discard request headers*. I try to comment the two lines and the browser show a connection reset page. I guess the server socket receive buffer is full, but I don't know the specific reason. Could anyone explain it?
[source code](https://github.com/zombiesh/tinyhttpd/blob/master/tinyhttpd/httpd.c)

```
/* Send a regular file to the client.  Use headers, and report */

void serve_file(int client, const char *filename) {
    FILE *resource = NULL;
    int numchars = 1;
    char buf[1024];

    buf[0] = 'A'; buf[1] = '\0';

    //why?
    while ((numchars > 0) && strcmp("\n", buf))  /* read & discard request headers */
        numchars = get_line(client, buf, sizeof(buf));

    resource = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (resource == NULL)
        not_found(client);
    else {
        headers(client, filename); //send headers to tcp buffer
        cat(client, resource); //send index.html to tcp buffer
    }
    fclose(resource);
}
```

Comment: The browser doesn't expect a HTTP resonse before the server has even acknowledged the HTTP request. You need to read the request first. Whether you actually need the information or not is irrelevant. It just reads a full HTTP header message (e.g. a full GET request)

Comment: As far as I know the acknowledges are sent by operating system regardless the application reads data from buffer or not. What can be a problem is the server must start sending a response after receiving request but the code without line may start sending response even before the client is still sending request headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you observed is a standard socket behavior.

If data received from a peer has not been read by the application and the application calls `close` on the socket then OS does not do the usual TCP connection finalization. It resets the connection immediately instead finalization. If application really wants gracefully close the connection when there is unread data in the received buffer then it must call `shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR)` before calling `close`.

And why is the socket API implemented that way? Because this handling can avoid dos attacks. If `close` executes normal TCP session finalization then following attack is possible:

- A malicious client opens a TCP connection
- The server accepts the connection and starts receiving data
- The client sends a continuous stream of let say random data
- The server quickly detects that received data is wrong and calls `close` on the socket.
- `close` just sends a `FIN` and then waits for the peer close. Server resources remain allocated because normal `FIN` just close the direction towards the client. The client still may send data and the recv buffer would not be freed.

But when the close initiates connection reset then resources related to this TCP connection is freed immediately. A dos attack is then a bit more complicated.

See https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-c-programming/msg01345.html for more details.

Comment: Exactly. I got a similar answer from another website, but it didn't tell me why the socket API implemented that way. Thanks for explaining so detailedly : ). I can't vote because my reputation is less 15, but thank you very much.